# Symfony2, DoctrineParamConverter.php, Entity Object not found

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have corrected the text, because after the re-installation, the DoctrineParamConverter complains about another entity.

> Entity\Dish object not found, in vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/Request/ParamConverter/DoctrineParamConverter.php at line 66. Logs starts with message: " INFO - Matched route "dish_show" `.

I have DishController.php blue3Action, which has no any relation with route "dish_show".

I was working normally for a week. Today I start getting this error, already for the 3rd hour.

1. I have checked routing.yml and controllers that there is nowhere double entries.
2. I have cleaned cache:
   cache:clear
   doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
   doctrine:cache:clear-entity-region
   doctrine:cache:clear-result
   doctrine:cache:clear-query-region
   doctrine:cache:clear-query
   doctrine:cache:clear-collection-region
3. I have run
   `sudo composer update`,
   when  `sudo composer remove "doctrine/doctrine-bundle"`
   when,  `sudo composer require "doctrine/doctrine-bundle"`.
4. Nothing helped. I deleted database, and recreated the database with tables. I am getting the error:

   > Entity\Dish object not found.

Which cache I have to delete, to get rid of this error?

5. I have updated symfony using  `symfony self-update`, but this did not help.
6. I have restarted the computer several times.
7. I have made a new project, recreated bundle, entities, crud, templates and custom actions. Now i am getting the error `Entity\Dish object not found` for the url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dish/blue3` with the first line in the log `INFO - Matched route "dish_show".`   - whereas said route is not related to the url. The url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dish/blue3` invokes Controller Action blue3Action and template `/var/www/RecB1_28_c/src/Rec/RecipBundle/Resources/views/dish/blue3.html.twig`, but route "dish_show" is not involved in them.

I am using url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dish/blue3`

This url is related to the `blue3Action` action in DishController.php (p.s. word blue comes from blueberries):

```
    /**
     * Lists all Dish entities.
     *
     * @Route("/blue3", name="blue3")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function blue3Action(Request $request)
{
        
    $post = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();  

    if ($post->request->has('submit')) { 
        
        $names=$em->getClassMetadata('Rec\RecipBundle\Entity\Nutr')->getFieldNames();
        $fields=array_flip($names);            
        
        $nutr3valparam=$post->request->get('nutr3valparam');  
        $decdisharr3 = json_decode($nutr3valparam, true);
        
        $arrdiff =  array_diff_key( $fields, $decdisharr3 );

        
        if( isset($decdisharr3) && !empty($decdisharr3) ) {

             $entity = new Nutr();
            //$em->getRepository('RecRecipBundle:Nutr')->persistOwn($decdisharr3);
            foreach ($decdisharr3 as $key=>$arr){
                if(!empty($key)) {                    
                   // $arr = json_decode($obj, true);
                    $amount = !empty($arr['amount']) ? $arr['amount'] : ""; 
                    $kcalarr = [ "Calories", 'FromSSSCarbohydrate',  'FromSSSFat', 'FromSSSProtein',
 'FromSSSAlcohol' ];
                    if( in_array($key, $kcalarr) ) {
                        $meas = 'kcal'; 
                    } else {
                        $meas =  !empty($arr['meassure']) ? $arr['meassure'] : "";
                    }//appends kcal where needed
                    $dv =  !empty($arr['dv']) ? $arr['dv'] : "";
                    $propstr = ''.$key."___".$amount."___".$meas."___".$dv;
                        //$entity->setKey($propstr) $entity->setCalories=("Calories___100___kca;___1%");
                    $method = "set".''.print_r( ucfirst($key), true) ;
                    if( is_string($key) ) { $this->print_ext( $key, "key"); }
                    if( is_string($method)) { $this->print_ext($method, "method"); }
                    if( is_string($propstr)) { $this->print_ext($propstr, "propstr"); }
                    $entity->{$method}($propstr);
                } //  if(!is_empty($key))
            }
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

          return $this->render('RecRecipBundle::dish/blue3.html.twig', array(
              'nutr3valparam'=> "", 
          ) );        
          
        // if( isset($decdisharr3) && !empty($decdisharr3) ) {
        } else { print_r("append_error"); }

    //if ($post->request->has('submit'))
    } else { $nutr3valparam=''; }

    return $this->render('RecRecipBundle::dish/blue3.html.twig', array(
        'nutr3valparam'=> $nutr3valparam, 
    ) );
    
    }  //   public function blue3Action(Request $request
```

And uses template `/var/www/RecB1_28_c/src/Rec/RecipBundle/Resources/views/dish/blue3.html.twig` :

```
{% extends "RecRecipBundle::base.html.twig" %}
         
{% block body %}

   <br>  <a href="#" id="click_me">Click Me</a> 
   
  <br>  Form with hidden input. Submit to save to database.
<form action="/dish/blue3" method="post"  id="dish_blue3" name="recrecipbundle_dish_blue3">
Title: <input type="text" name="title"  id="dish_blue3_title" ><br>
Description: <input type="text" name="descr" id="dish_blue3_descr"><br>            
{# append in jquery   <input type="hidden" id="nutr-valparam" name="nutr-valparam" value={{nutr-valparam}} ></input> #}
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save found data to Nutr">
</form>  
 
<br><br>  THE FILE TO BE ABALISED: (very long copy of some htlml document which is anallysed by jquery script after user click, in order to extract the data. This part is fully functioning, i can check it separately as php script.) <br><br> 
     
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %} {% endblock %}                
{% block javascripts %}
   {{ parent() }}
    {% javascripts 
        '@RecRecipBundle/Resources/js/datasear.js'    
     %}
     <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>   
   {% endjavascripts %}   
{% endblock %}
```

Below is the showAction() (route `"dish_show"`) from DishController.php, The error starts from the route "dish_show", nevertheless, this route is not related to the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dish/blue3` which generates the error.

```
  /**
     * Finds and displays a Dish entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="dish_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function showAction(Dish $dish)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($dish);

        return $this->render('RecRecipBundle::dish/show.html.twig', array(
            'dish' => $dish,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

This is routing.yml

```
rec_recip:
    resource: "@RecRecipBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

rec_recip_nutr:
    resource: "@RecRecipBundle/Controller/NutrController.php"
    type:     annotation

rec_recip_dish:
    resource: "@RecRecipBundle/Controller/DishController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

The error in the log:

```
  INFO - Matched route "dish_show".
    INFO - Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token.
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest".
    DEBUG - SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.title AS title2, t0.descr AS descr3, t0.prod AS prod4, t0.highestT AS highestT5, t0.time AS time6, t0.kcal AS kcal7, t0.keyw AS keyw8, t0.main_nutr AS main_nutr9, t0.descrV AS descrV10, t0.prod6 AS prod611, t0.prep6 AS prep612, t0.var6 AS var613, t0.prod1 AS prod114, t0.prep1 AS prep115, t0.var1 AS var116, t0.prod2 AS prod217, t0.prep2 AS prep218, t0.var2 AS var219, t0.prod3 AS prod320, t0.prep3 AS prep321, t0.var3 AS var322, t0.prod4 AS prod423, t0.prep4 AS prep424, t0.var4 AS var425, t0.prod5 AS prod526, t0.prep5 AS prep527, t0.var5 AS var528 FROM tdish t0 WHERE t0.id = ?
    ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "Rec\RecipBundle\Entity\Dish object not found." at /var/www/RecB1_28_c/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 7396
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
```

Stack Trace (Plain Text)

```
[1] Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: Rec\RecipBundle\Entity\Dish object not found.
    at n/a
        in /var/www/RecB1_28_c/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 7396

    at Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter->apply(object(Request), object(ParamConverter))
        in /var/www/RecB1_28_c/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 7576

    at Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ParamConverterManager->applyConverter(object(Request), object(ParamConverter))
        in /var/www/RecB1_28_c/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 7549

    at Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ParamConverterManager->apply(object(Request), array('dish' => object(ParamConverter)))
        in /var/www/RecB1_28_c/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 7283

    at Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener->onKernelController(object(FilterControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
        in  line 

    at call_user_func(array(object(ParamConverterListener), 'onKernelController'), object(FilterControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
        in /var/www/RecB1_28_c/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php line 61

    at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(object(FilterControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
        in  line 

    at call_user_func(object(WrappedListener), object(FilterControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
        in /var/www/RecB1_28_c/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1853

    at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.controller', object(FilterControllerEvent))
        in /var/www/RecB1_28_c/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1771

    at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.controller', object(FilterControllerEvent))
        in /var/www/RecB1_28_c/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 132

    at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.controller', object(FilterControllerEvent))
        in /var/www/RecB1_28_c/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php line 132

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
        in /var/www/RecB1_28_c/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php line 62

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /var/www/RecB1_28_c/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php line 69

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /var/www/RecB1_28_c/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php line 185

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in /var/www/RecB1_28_c/web/app_dev.php line 30

    at require('/var/www/RecB1_28_c/web/app_dev.php')
        in /var/www/RecB1_28_c/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/router_dev.php line 40
```

Stack Trace

```
in app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 7396


    }
    }
    if (null === $object && false === $configuration->isOptional()) {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('%s object not found.', $class));
    }
    $request->attributes->set($name, $object);
    return true;

 at DoctrineParamConverter ->apply (object(Request), object(ParamConverter))
in app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 7576  +
at ParamConverterManager ->applyConverter (object(Request), object(ParamConverter))
in app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 7549  +
at ParamConverterManager ->apply (object(Request), array('dish' => object(ParamConverter)))
in app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 7283  +
at ParamConverterListener ->onKernelController (object(FilterControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
at call_user_func (array(object(ParamConverterListener), 'onKernelController'), object(FilterControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php at line 61  +
at WrappedListener ->__invoke (object(FilterControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
at call_user_func (object(WrappedListener), object(FilterControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
in app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 1853  +
at EventDispatcher ->doDispatch (array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.controller', object(FilterControllerEvent))
in app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 1771  +
at EventDispatcher ->dispatch ('kernel.controller', object(FilterControllerEvent))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php at line 132  +
at TraceableEventDispatcher ->dispatch ('kernel.controller', object(FilterControllerEvent))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php at line 132  +
at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php at line 62  +
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php at line 69  +
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php at line 185  +
at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
in web/app_dev.php at line 30  +
at require ('/var/www/RecB1_28_c/web/app_dev.php')
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/router_dev.php at line 40  +
```

Comment: Please show the controller that is related to the `nutr_show` action and how your route configuration looks like.

Comment: What is the error in the log? not the info log message.

Comment: how to check the error in the log? I have reinstalled whole project and now i am getting the error "Entity\Dish object not found", which is not related to the action `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dish/blue3` at all.

Comment: give me some time, i am double checking the template

Comment: i can not find nor error, now where i refer to the route `dish_show`

Comment: I left this for later. Seems better build own MVC and website than use frameworks.

Comment: Got this same error, had defined the route *link* name a second time in another controller. So check your route links annotations above your controllers.